# Signing an iPhone application with developer certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new in developing an iPhone application with a developer certificate and I got confused when read the steps provided online.

I have created an application in Xcode which I named it finalApp and before I tried to test on  my device I tried it on the simulator and it works fine.I have registered for a developer certificate and I have my Iphone developer certificate in my Keychain Access which looks like this:
[image]

What I did afterwards was to go to my application's build setting and change all my code singing to this cert which is under **Identities without Provisioning Profiles**( I suspect something I did here might be wrong or incomplete). Next I change my running device to my device name which is `iPhone`. After which I ran the program and it gives me this message.

```
Code Sign error:A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier **None.finalApp** could not be found.
```

So based on this error I am guessing that I have missed out creating a provisioning profile? Or is there any thing else that I left out? What should I do in order to install my application in my iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of ERROR is come because of **Bundle identifier** are diffrent.

In your **application.plist** change **Bundle identifier** as **com.yourcomanyname.appname** or what ever you used during creating the App Id.

in your case you are using **None.finalApp** which are not matching with your Bundle Id.

[image: use same Bundel Id as you use here]

Comment: Hi is the application plist under the supporting files, which is finalApp-Info.plist for my case. In that file my Bundle identifier is None.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)

Comment: yes in date place enter com.yourcomanyname.yourappname as you anter during creating app your app id

Comment: Is there any means of getting that Bundle ID without logging into the developer account as I do not have the developer credentials with me? Another team member has the credentials so I guess I need to wait for him to return then.

Comment: No. For that you have to purchas developer account or comapny account. If your team member has credential than you use it.